# Comparison between X/Y and X/|Y| when X and Y are iid Normal(0,1) (Cauchy distribution)

Tags: normal-distribution, cauchy-distribution

[image]

I was studying mathematical statistics written by Joe Blitzstein when I encountered the derivation of the PDF of Cauchy distribution.

**I cannot understand why the distribution is the same between X/Y and X/|Y|** (that is, **why P(X/Y < t) = P(X/|Y| < t)**).

I know that since X and Y are iid Normal(0,1), they each have symmetry when viewed separately, and because of that, X and -X, Y and -Y all follow a standard normal distribution. Maybe this has something to do with what the author is talking about when he mentions "symmetry of the standard Normal distribution".

However, when I see these random variables combined (for example, in the form of a ratio like the image), it's very difficult to comprehend how the symmetry of X and Y can lead to **X/Y** and **X/|Y|** having the same distribution.

Someone told me that because X, -X, Y, -Y are identically distributed, both X/Y and -X/Y must be identically distributed because both are the ratios of standard normal.

Well I also understand that, but in the context of the image, there is an additional range restriction which causes variability to **X/|Y|**: the signs of **X/|Y|** keep changing according to the range of Y (whenever Y>0 it will be **X/Y** but when Y<0 it will switch to **-X/Y**). If **-X/Y** remained in the same form (if **"-X/Y"** kept staying as **"-X/Y"**) regardless of the range of Y, I would get it, but in this case, **X/|Y|** will keep switching back and forth from **X/Y** to **-X/Y** depending on the range of Y.

It is difficult to wrap my head around how this constant variability of the sign as Y ranges from negative infinity to positive infinity, will not impact the equality of the distributions of **X/Y** and **X/|Y|** (**P(X/Y < t) = P(X/|Y| < t)**).

Sorry if my post seemed too long/redundant but I wanted to convey exactly which part of the logic I'm not getting it right now. I really wish to understand this section clearly before moving on, so I would appreciate it if someone who understands what I'm struggling with can help me out.

Comment: Have you considered plotting contours of the $X/Y$ and $X/|Y|$ values? More technically, $(X,Y)$ has a symmetry group $\mathcal D_4$ of order $8.$ It's generated by the (linear) maps $(X,Y)\to(-X,Y),$ $(X,Y)\to(X,-Y),$ and $(X,Y)\to(Y,X).$ You can exploit this to reduce any probability calculation involving $(X,Y)$ to a calculation involving events within a fundamental domain of that group, such as $\{(x,y)\mid 0\le x\lt y\}.$